# Using React as a frontend and node+express as a backend -- on Button click fetch data from SQL and display in a react Grid

Tags: reactjs, express, react-fullstack

In my React application , I wanted search any random ID in text box and than
click **Search** button , if that id is present in table so i wanted to fetch the respective record's from table and display the record's on UI.
I am using node Js and Express Js as a  backend.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.